# Data precision problems between Oracle and SQL Server - number vs float

Tags: sql-server-2008, numbers, oracle10g

We want to move data from Oracle to SQL Server, and make it available to developers for several reasons.  I've read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151817.aspx) that the proper mapping from Oracle NUMBER is to SQL Server FLOAT.

We have a problem with dyadic rationals.  In Oracle, it could have the value of 5.2, and it appears that in SQL Server it is not exactly that.  (The number of significant digits can vary wildly within one field.)

A co-worker was connecting to both using Access and seeing the data issue.  In SQL Server, I did a query on a huge table where one field was equal to 5.2, and got the same count as Oracle.

```
select count(*) from result where samp_aliquot_size = 5.6
```

In both Oracle and SQL Server, I get the count 1118.  So then, I did a sum from both:

```
select sum(samp_aliquot_size) from result where samp_aliquot_size = 5.6
```

and in Oracle I get 6260.8, in SQL Server I get 6260.80000000009.

The requirements for this say that the data will be an "exact match".  What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question "The requirements for this say that the data will be an "exact match". What is the best way to achieve that?" is to move the dyadic rational from Oracle to SQL Server.  SQL Server may then calculate the decimal representation from the EXACT dyadic rational.  Do we know what the requested accuracy form Oracle was  when the decimal was calculated?

If the dyadic rational is not available; the Oracle value should be moved into a varchar string in SQL Server.  Converting to a string will retain the "exact" representation of the dyadic rational calculated by Oracle.

I used this Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) for my dyadic rational defination:

I am intrested to find where the numeric conversion is inexact.  To identify the location could you import the data into two SQL Server columns, one column as varchar and the other as float.  After the import output a list of rows where varchar  not = Cast(real as varchar)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? If I import the fields as varchar, shouldn't it look correct? I have a temp SQL table, with the id field, and then the field three times, as float, decimal(38,17), and nvarchar(100). In my SSIS package, I copy the first straight across, and have data conversions to make a decimal (scale 17) and unicode string length 100 for the other two. I get values of (0.005, 0.00500000000000000, 5.0000000000000001E-3) and (0.1, 0.10000000000000000, 0.10000000000000001). Why is the last, the STRING field showing imprecision?!

Comment: The string is not the string showing an imprecision. There are two more places in the string display VS the decimal display. I believe there is rounding during the conversion from Oracle.   Prior to converting the value to SQL cast the number to a character value in Oracle and see if all the data is exact.

Comment: I found this aticle by sql server customer support.   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/11/01/how-it-works-sql-paring-of-number-s-numeric-and-float-conversions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The mapping table also shows

```
NUMBER([1-38]) -> NUMERIC([1-38])
```

Have you considered fixed precision in SQL Server rather than floating if it is within Oracle's more limited DECIMAL range (which matches SQL Server)

Given [Oracle's documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/datatypes.php) states NUMBER is fixed anyway. [And here](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html)

Comment: Our Oracle isn't using NUMBER(p,s), they are just using NUMBER.  So, for one field, I might have 33293, 3.4, and 0.0000000382493.  They can and do vary wildly, as I said.  If Oracle has 5.2 and I have 5.200000000000000, that doesn't really match either, does it?  Isn't that implying precision that doesn't exist?